# Cairo on M1 chip (gmp.h) error fixed solition

Tags: macos, gmp

[image]
To make mine more generic, try:

CFLAGS=-I`brew --prefix gmp`/include LDFLAGS=-L`brew --prefix gmp`/lib pip install ecdsa fastecdsa sympy

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/nile/issues/22
This seems to be an issue with the Cairo programming language on apple's M1 computers. I read on the Cairo discord that you were able to solve it. Leaving a few success stories taken from the Cairo discord server for anybody stumbling upon this very problem:

```
CFLAGS=-Ibrew --prefix gmp/include LDFLAGS=-Lbrew --prefix gmp/lib pip install ecdsa fastecdsa sympy
```